# Basic hard surface editing: What is the quickest way to make a frame around an opening?

Tags: modeling

As the title says, I want to inset a frame here like a window frame in a wall or in a box.[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you can do is create some additional edge loops, select the inner side faces, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Extrude Along Normals* (enable the *Offset Even* option in the Operator box), then extrude the top faces up:

[image]